# Creating query and filtering for Coherence cache

Tags: oracle-coherence

I have a simple POJO:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

And I want to be able to create an index on a cache that will then allow me to execute the following pseudo-query:

`find me all the people whose name is EQUAL to John and their age is GREATERTHAN 30`

I've tried `MultiExtractor` which appears to create the index I want, but when I construct the query using the `Filter` objects, I seem to still end up with un-optimised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to add property accessors:

```
public class Person {
  public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

Now you can query:

```
// find me all the people whose name is EQUAL to
// John and their age is GREATERTHAN 30
Filter filter = new AndFilter(
                    new EqualsFilter("getName", "John"),
                    new GreaterFilter("getAge", Integer.valueOf(30));
Set setKeys = cache.keySet(filter);
```

You can also code that filter in SQL. See: https://community.oracle.com/message/11217211#11217211

Other resources:

- http://vimeo.com/51314443
- http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/api_cq.htm#COHDG5263
- https://www.youtube.com/user/OracleCoherence